# Passing Command line arguments

Tags: java, notepad++, command-line-arguments

In my pc I'm always having a problem with running my java code in cmd . It shows "**error loading main class**" (though I commented out project name, set the classpath,set the PATH variable, but still no change) all the time. My teacher told me to create a new file and store my .java files there and edit it with notepad++ and create a .bat format file.

But I'm not sure about the whole process because I tried to do that it showed error again "**error loading main class**" (may be I missed some steps). Can anyone please help me with this?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: what is the error? Be specific and clear about it.

Comment: Also, please show the command you used.

Comment: Maybe your teacher should teach you how to use an IDE. You'll use an IDE once you're employed. Companies are not looking for developers how write code in Notepad. An IDE has many benefits.

Comment: i'm trying to build a chat messenger with one server multiple client so i need cmd to for passing messages to different client at the same time, can i do it (running same file several times at the same time)by passing arguments in netbeans or intellij?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have this directory layout:

```
myproject/
    src/
        mypackage/
            MyClass1.java
            MyClass2.java
    target/
```

... and let's also asume that you open a shell with `myproject` as the working directory.

You should compile your source code and store the produced .class files into the `target` dir. For example:

```
javac -d target src\mypackage\*.java
```

And finally, to execute the `main` method in `MyClass1`, you should execute this:

```
java -classpath target mypackage.MyClass1 <arguments...>
```

Of corse, if you needed more third-party libraries, then you must add them to the classpath:

In Windows:

```
java -classpath target;library1.jar;library2.jar mypackage.MyClass1 <arguments...>
```

In Unix:

```
java -classpath target:library1.jar:library2.jar mypackage.MyClass1 <arguments...>
```